# How to Integrate Integration Tests Using Cucumber 6 and Maven

Tags: maven, cucumber, integration-testing, integration

I really need help here.

**Objective:** Run my cucumber integration tests using Cucumber-Java8 version 6.7.0 with Maven 3.6.3.

**Actual Scenario:** When I run maven using this command: `$ mvn clean verify -Pintegration-tests` I am receiving this result.

```
xxxxx @ xxx <Project Name> % mvn clean verify -Pintegration-tests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------< <Project Name> >----------
[INFO] Building <Project Name> 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ <Project Name> ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/<home>/Documents/repos/xxx/<Project Name>/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.1.0:add-test-source (add-source) @ <Project Name> ---


***[INFO] Test Source directory: /Users/<home>/Documents/repos/xxxx/<Project Name>/src/testintegration added.***


[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.1.0:add-test-resource (add-resource) @ <Project Name ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ <Project Name> ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 13 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ <Project Name> ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 223 source files to /Users/<home>/Documents/repos/xxx/<Project Name>
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ <Project Name> ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 15 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ n<Project Name> ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!

...

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ <Project Name> ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ <Project Name> ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/<home>/Documents/repos/xxxx/<Project Name> -server/target/<Project Name>.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.2:integration-test (default) @ <Project Name> ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.2:verify (default) @ <Project Name> ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.484 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-17T13:07:50+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I didn't put any code in my Definition Class except "Sysout" and assertTrue. The Integration Test runs when I use a runner that I created trigger by Intellij.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/testintegration/java/features"},
    glue = {"steps"},
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"},
    publish = true)
public class RunCucumberIT {
```

## Code Scenario Actual

[Sctructure of the Project - Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdwYQ.png)

### Maven File - Snipped

```
 <!-- Integration tests -->

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>integration-tests</id>

      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        <cucumber.plugin>json:target/report.json</cucumber.plugin>
        <cucumber.filter.tags>@wip</cucumber.filter.tags>
      </properties>

      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <sources>
                    <source>src/testintegration/</source>
                  </sources>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>add-resource</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <resources>
                    <resource>
                      <directory>src/testintegration/resources/features</directory>
                    </resource>
                  </resources>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <!-- block unit tests execution -->
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <cucumber.plugin>${cucumber.plugin}</cucumber.plugin>
                <cucumber.filter.tags>${cucumber.filter.tags}</cucumber.filter.tags>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>


      <dependencies>
        <!-- Cucumber -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
          <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
          <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>6.2.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

### Definition Class

```
package steps;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import io.cucumber.java8.En;


public class Authorization implements En {

  public Authorization() {

    Given("the system knows about the following attributes",
        (io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) -> {
          System.out.println("AUTHORIZATION GIVEN TEST");
          assertTrue(true);
        });

    When("the client request POST \\/login", () -> {
      System.out.println("AUTHORIZATION When TEST");
      assertTrue(true);
    });

    Then("the response should be JSON", (io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) -> {
      System.out.println("AUTHORIZATION Then TEST");
      assertTrue(true);
    });

  }
}
```

### Part of Feature File

```
Feature: Authorization

  @wip
  Scenario: Login into account

...
```

### Runner Class - (When I trigger this class by Intellij my test run correctly

```
package runner;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/testintegration/java/features"},
    glue = {"steps"},
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"},
    publish = true)
public class RunCucumberIT {
  
}
```

I used this page here to try to do work my tests. But to be honest I don't know if I am doing something wrong or the article is missing something.
[Here is the website.(weblogism)](https://www.weblogism.com/item/334/integration-tests-with-cucumber-jvm-selenium-and-maven)

Please, could someone check the Pom.xml file? I think I am missing something.

Many thanks if someone can help me here.

Cheers,

Comment: Try and make your problem even smaller. Try a single JUnit test. Run it as `mvn test`. Then add a simple JUnit integration test and run it with `mvn verify`. Then add Cucumber but leave out all the extras you added.

Comment: Hi @M.P.Korstanje, many thanks but I've already tried this. When I run simple unit tests then can be found and run successfully. My problem is when I try to run my definition class based on my feature file. Many Thanks!!! More suggestions I'll be happy. :-)

Comment: Then you might be better of making a new question that shows exactly with this much simpler configuration what doesn't work. You've got too many moving parts involved right now.  Remove everything you don't actually need to show the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje, I solved the problem partially. I found out that I have to use a library from Cucumber. <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${cucuber.io.version}</version>
    </dependency> but the integration tests that are using just JUnit stopped to work. When I find the solution I'll post here. Many Thanks ! :)